# R:shiny updateCheckboxGroup to update when pressed

Tags: r, checkbox, auto-update, shiny

So I want to make a function for my app, so that whenever I press the button it updates with the data from a select bar that I have.

Basically, "choose an item on the selectInput bar"->"Press GO"->"checkbox added"
Likewise I'd like to have the checkboxes disappear when they are clicked.

This is what I have so far, it doesn't seem to work for some reason :/

```
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Example"),

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("pet", "Select a pet", choices = c("cat","dog","bird"), selected = c('cat'))
      ,actionButton('on','GO')
      ,tags$hr()
      ,checkboxGroupInput('levels', 'Levels', choices = c('bear'))

    ),

    mainPanel()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
      lvl<-reactive(unlist(input$levels))

      observe({
      if(input$on==0) return()
      isolate({

      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "levels", choices = c(input$pet,lvl()))
                               })#iso
      })#obs
  }
))
```

Answer (score 2):

so for all who wondered I figured it out, here is my code:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Example"),

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("pet", "Select a pet", choices = c("cat","dog","bird"), selected = c('cat'))
      ,actionButton('on','GO')
      ,tags$hr()
      ,checkboxGroupInput('levels', 'Levels', choices = c('bear'),selected=c('bear'))

    ),

    mainPanel()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    lvl<-reactive(unlist(input$levels))

    observe({
      if(input$on==0) return()
      isolate({

        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "levels", choices = c(input$pet,lvl())
                                 ,selected=c(input$pet,lvl()))
      })#iso
    })#obs
    observe({
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "levels", choices = c(lvl())
                               ,selected=c(lvl()))
    })
  }
))
```